# Objectify - how efficient is a key-only query filtered by ancestor?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to get all the children of a given parent entity efficiently. The only way to do that now is to use a query in objectify, which is not efficient because it bypasses the cache. Objectify-4 adds hybrid queries, which you can mimic in Objectify 3.x by issuing a key only query and then doing a batch get on those keys.

My question is how efficient is a key-only query that filters using an ancestor? Something like:

```
ofy.query(Car.class).ancestor(someKey).fetchKeys();
```

I don't want to get all keys for all "Cars" here, I only want "Cars" that belong to a specific parent.

Comment: What do you mean "efficient"?

Answer (score 2):

Your query will get all `Car` entities which are children of given parent entity.

[Billing docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing) state that keys-only query costs 1 read + 1 small operation per retrieved entity.